# Change windows welcome gif/spinner

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

Is it possible to change the spinner on windows 7 default welcome screen?

I want to make it look like windows 10, and I know it has to do with authui.dll but Resource Hacker doesn't really help me change it.

Please can you help me change it?

[image: welcome screen here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it possible to change the spinner on windows 7 default welcome screen?

I don't know what it looks like on Windows 10, but the "spinner" is the "Busy" mouse pointer.

To change the mouse pointer:

- Start > "Control Panel" > "Mouse".
- Select the "Pointers" panel.
- In the "Customise" list, scroll down till you see the "Busy" pointer and select it.

  [image]
- Click "Browse".
- Select a new cursor and "Open" it.

  [image]
- Click OK.

Comment: Mouse pointers are a per-user preference, so even if that were the solution, doing it from the control panel wouldn't affect how it looks before a user is logged in.

Comment: @WesSayeed Replacing the cursor file might work. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

The welcome Spinner resource is stored in imageres.dll, if you open it with resource hacker, it is in bitmap group, if i'm right, theres in resource number 50002.

You can use tool called "W10 Animation Logon W7" by alexgal from deviantart to change spinner to look like windows 10.

sorry bad english

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.